# Flickering screen VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba

**Setting**

I have created a report in excel which extracts data from an API into a PowerPivot data model, which runs several pivot tables and graphs. Along with this, there is a very simple macro that updates the entire workbook, so new data is extracted.

**Problem**

When i press the button i've made for the macro the headlines, textboxes and images inside the report start flickering and once the proces is done, they dissapear entirely only to be shown when one presses on them. They appear to become hidden.

I'm looking for a way to solve this - been googling several ways to do it, but it doesn't seem to work

**Tried solutions**

I've tried several solutions, along with inserting my code in something similar as seen below and also simply wrapping it around `Application.ScreenUpdating`

```
Sub startcode()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Call myrunningsub()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub myrunningsub()
    'MY CODE HERE
End Sub
```

I'v also tested this:

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Const WM_SETREDRAW = &HB
Sub DataRefresh()
    SendMessage Application.hwnd, WM_SETREDRAW, 0&, 0&
   MY CODE HERE
    SendMessage Application.hwnd, WM_SETREDRAW, 1&, 0&        
End Sub
```

**My Code**

```
Sub workbook_refreshAll()

Sheets("Employee Analysis").Range("J5") = ""

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Sheets("Employee Analysis").Range("J5").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=today()"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are known best practices for VBA in Excel that can make your code faster.

**#1. Don't Copy and Paste**

The Copy and Paste (or **PasteSpecial**) functions are slow. It is about 25 times faster to use the following to copy and paste values.

```
    Range("A1:Z100").value = Range("A101:Z200").value
```

If you are doing it this way your Code will Probably work. There is maybe a problem with the Mamory if your are doing this on to many Rows.

**#2. Calculation**

Normally, Excel will recalculate a cell or a range of cells when that cell's or range's precedents have changed.  This may cause your workbook to recalculate too often, which will slow down performance.  You can prevent Excel from recalculating the workbook by using the statement:

```
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

At the end of your code, you can set the calculation mode back to automatic with the statement:

```
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Remember, though, that when the calculation mode is **xlCalculationManual**, Excel doesn't update values in cells.  If your macro relies on an updated cell value, you must force a Calculate event, with the `.Calculate` method like `Worksheets(1).Calculate`.

**#3. ScreenUpdating**

Every time VBA writes data to the worksheet it refreshes the screen image that you see. Refreshing the image is a considerable drag on performance. The following command turns off screen updates.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

At the end of the macro use the following command to turn screen updates back on.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**#4 Ignore Events**

If you have a `Worksheet_Change` event implemented for the Sheet1 of your workbook. Any time a cell or range is altered on the Sheet1, the `Worksheet_Change` event will run. So if you have a standard macro that manipulates several cells on Sheet1, each time a cell on that sheet is changed, your macro has to pause while the `Worksheet_Change` event runs. You can imagine how this behavior would slow down your macro.

```
    Application.EnableEvents = False
```

At the end of your code, you can set the `EnableEvents` mode back to True with the statement:

```
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: No, that is not what `with` does. It simply stores a reference to the object into a temporary variable which can be done manually too. It does not compress a series of changes into one complex change.

Comment: Agree. Removed.

Comment: I would have reworded it rather than removed. It does speed things up if you actually re-query the same object on each line for several lines, such as `worksheets("...").range("...").Property1`, `worksheets("...").range("...").Property2`, and it certainly makes it look clean. It just doesn't have the magical property of compressing a stream of changes into one.

Comment: The combination of no 2, 3 and 4 did the trick! - Thank you for your help!